# How to join these lists' elements?

Tags: python, list, join, merge

Given the following `list_a`,
I want get a `list_b = [[42,43,46,45,44],[47,48,51,50]]`.
I wrote this code, but I can not get the result I want.

```
list_a = [('42', '43'), ('43', '46'), ('44', '45'), ('45', '46'), ('47', '48'), ('48', '51'), ('49', '50'), ('50', '51')]
list_b =[]
for i in range(len(list_a)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(list_a)):
        if  list_a[i][0] ==  list_a[j][0]:
            list_b.insert(0,list_a[i][1])
            list_b.append(list_a[i][0])
            list_b.append(list_a[j][1])
            continue
        if  list_a[i][0] ==  list_a[j][1]:
            list_b.insert(0,list_a[i][1])
            list_b.append(list_a[i][0])
            list_b.append(list_a[j][0])
            continue
        if  list_a[i][1] ==  list_a[j][1]:
            list_b.insert(0,list_a[i][0])
            list_b.append(list_a[i][1])
            list_b.append(list_a[j][1])
            continue
        if  list_a[i][1] ==  list_a[j][1]:
            list_b.insert(0,list_a[i][0])
            list_b.append(list_a[i][1])
            list_b.append(list_a[j][0])
            continue
print(list_b)
```

The process is this:
compare any two list one by one,if any two list elements have a same number, then join these two lists into one list.
`['42', '43'], ['43', '46']`  ==> `[42,43,46]`
then, compare the new list and any othere list ,if any two list elements have a same number,then join these two list to one list.
`[42,43,46], ['45', '46']` ==> `[42,43,46,45]`
it is like join some segments to multi-segment line.

Comment: What did you try? Please post your code and explain what did not work.

Comment: I do not grasp the connection between the order of the list elements and the desired output.

Comment: imagine that：these are some segments ,every segment have two coordinates，if two segment have a same coordinates,then join these segment ,the finish result is get all coordinates in the same Multisegment line. these segments  maybe in several different Multisegment line,then the result maybe is a  Two-dimensional list

Comment: I my opinion this is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: but it is。 in order to simplify the issue,i use these numbers replace coordinates.

Comment: Even with the clarification in the comments, I am not quite sure what the problem is well defined: Just consider `list_a = [('42', '43'), ('43', '46'),('43','45')]`.
How would the result look like?

Comment: [[42,43,46],[43,45]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
def get_groups(start, data, _seen=[], _current=[]):
   vals = set(filter(lambda x:x not in _seen, [b for a, b in data if a == start] + [a for a, b in data if b == start]))
   if not vals:
     yield _current
     data = [(a, b) for a, b in data if a not in _seen and b not in _seen]
     if data:
       c, d = data[0][0], data[0][-1]
       yield from get_groups(c, data, _seen=_seen+[c, d], _current=[c, d])
       yield from get_groups(d, data, _seen=_seen+[c, d], _current=[c, d])
   else:
     for i in vals:
       if i not in _seen:
         yield from get_groups(i, data, _seen=_seen+[i], _current=_current+[i])

list_a = [('42', '43'), ('43', '46'), ('44', '45'), ('45', '46'), ('47', '48'), ('48', '51'), ('49', '50'), ('50', '51')]
def get_result(l):
  result = sorted(list(get_groups(l[0][0], l, _seen=[l[0][0]], _current=[l[0][0]])), key=len, reverse=True)
  return [a for i, a in enumerate(result) if all(any(c not in b for c in a) for b in result[:i])]

print(get_result(list_a))
```

Output:

```
[['42', '43', '46', '45', '44'], ['47', '48', '51', '50', '49']]
```

Comment: @JamesChen Glad to help!